# How can I separate or split a single mesh into two meshes?

Tags: mesh

**How can I separate or split a single mesh into two meshes? Once I have two separate meshes would it be possible to make one be “shade smooth” and the other “shade flat”?**

I am modeling a vehicle in blender using one mesh to make the shape of the car as a whole, however I find that the back of the car looks better when shaded flat as opposed to the front which looks better shaded smooth. Therefore I want to have the back as shaded flat and the front shaded smooth. My idea was to split the mesh in two and adjust each mesh in the way I wanted. If so how would I do this, and if this isn’t the way then how could I achieve the end goal I have in mind. Two parts of the single mesh shaded differently (flat and smooth).

Comment: Enter edit.  Select the faces that you want to separate.  'p' (separate) -> selection.  It's an okay thing to do, but better would be to use sharp edge markings (select edges of bits you want flat shaded, "mark sharp" operation.)

Comment: Hey :). Shading is set *per face* so simply select the faces and go *Face > Shade Flat*. No need to separate anything.

Comment: How can I select single faces in object mode then? Or am I meant to do this in edit mode, and therefore should I select all the faces of the part I want shaded flat.

Comment: @MateoL Yes, I meant in Edit mode :).

Comment: @Jachym Michal so I select the faces and then do go Face > shade flat, I am puzzled as I cannot seem to find where to do this. : (